# Create diff between two files based on specific column

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following problem.

Say I have 2 files:

A.txt

```
1    A1
2    A2
```

B.txt

```
1    B1
2    B2
3    B3
```

I want to make diff which is based only on values of first column, so the result should be

```
3     B3
```

How this problem can be solved with bash in linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[ awk ]](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) is your friend

```
awk 'NR==FNR{f[$1];next}{if($1 in f){next}else{print}}' A.txt B.txt
```

or more simply

```
awk 'NR==FNR{f[$1];next}!($1 in f){print}' A.txt B.txt
```

or even more simply

```
awk 'NR==FNR{f[$1];next}!($1 in f)' A.txt B.txt
```

---

**A bit of explanation will certainly help**

1. `NR` & `FNR` are awk built-in variables which stand for `total number of records - including current - processed so far` **and** `total number of records - including current - processed so far in the current file` **respectively** and they will be equal only for the first file processed.
2. `f[$1]` creates the array `f` at first and then adds `$1` as a key if the same key doesn't yet exist. If no value is assigned, then f[$1] is auto-initialized to zero, but this aspect doesn't find a use in your case
3. `next` goes to the next record with out processing rest of the awk script.
4. Note that `{if($1 in f){next}else{print}}` part will be processed only for the second (and subsequent if any) file/s.
5. `$1 in f` checks if the the key `$1` exists in the array `f`
6. The `if-else-print` part is self explanatory.
7. Note in the third version, the `{print}` is omitted coz the default action for awk is printing !!

---

Comment: Or more simply `awk 'NR==FNR{f[$1];next}!($1 in f)'`

Comment: @123 : I bet you're good in this.. :) Thankyou will add it to solution

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{array[$1];next} !($1 in array)' a.txt b.txt
3    B3
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this in `bash` but only if you are **really** not interested in the second column at all:

```
diff <(cut -f1 -d" " A.txt) <(cut -f1 -d" " B.txt)
```